# How do i get the <div> value using AngularJs

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to get the `<div>` value when click on it.

```
<div ng-repeat="y in data">
        <span ng-click="showDetails()" ng-model="searchText" >{{ y }} </span><br/>
    </div>
```

Below is my script code.

```
$scope.showDetails = function() {
    var searchTe = $scope.searchText;
}
```

When click on a dynamic `y` value, I need to get it. Could you please let me know how to get the value when click on that specific value using AngularJs?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `y` variable to your click handler:

```
<div ng-repeat="y in data">
    <span ng-click="showDetails(y)" ng-model="searchText" >{{ y }} </span><br/>
</div>
```

And let `showDetails` be a parametrized function:

```
$scope.showDetails = function(y) {
     //use y here
     var searchTe = $scope.searchText;
}
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0t8TqZ9rR8MLNTNzIOne?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It was not working."y" displays multiple values.I need to get the value which is clicked. Let us assume "y" displays A,B and C in dropdown. If i click on "A", i need to get A in function.

Comment: I think it works fine. Added a plunkr example in answer.

Comment: @Ramesh so dont use model $scope.searchText but variable y passed into function